# Where is Pb (lead) found in an immersion heater?

Tags: safety, heater

Clicking "Technical data" on [this page](https://www.backerspringfield.com/products/commercial/immersion-heaters.html) gives a pretty good overview of the composition of immersion heaters: Terminal, End Seal, Cold Pin, Alloy spiral, Sheath, and Insulation.  Having bought a RoadPro immersion heater for my on-the-road needs, I read on the label that it contains lead.  Not sure where, but the other immersion heaters that are sold on Amazon are sourced from China -- meaning that they won't disclose it, even if they also contain lead.

So I decided to buy lead test strips, and test the heater that I buy, to check whether it also has lead.  My question is, which of the above components can contain lead?

Comment: If it has a plug for the cigar lighter socket, I'd be amazed to find the wires weren't soldered to its contacts. Have you opened the plug if it has one?

Comment: Even if the wires were soldered, why would the solder contain lead with RoHS legislation being enforced on products for more than ten years now?

Comment: @justme - Sure, while the legislation is there - it's not necessarily enforced. I've been pulling apart dirt-cheap solar lights for a couple of weeks and I am yet to find one done with lead-free solder. Last week I had a 250gm reel of Loctite brand 60/40 delivered.

Comment: @enhzflep So have you been using a lead test strip to test whether the solder contains lead? p.s., at least they're complying with the "declaring lead" part of the legislation...

Comment: @Justme RoHS only applies in Europe.

Comment: @Alex - nope. Just going on the fact they're a dollar each and 190C is enough to melt the stuff that flows beautifully.

Comment: @enhzflep How do you clock the temperature at 190C?  I find that because of the reflective nature of solder, IR thermometers don't work to measure its temperature; also, since I have a 5V soldering iron, it doesn't produce enough heat to fully convey its temperature to a touch thermometer.  If this needs to be a separate SE question, let me know and I can ask it -- but if it has a simple answer, it would save me a lot of trouble in the future, including not needing lead test strips.  I just didn't think it was possible...

Comment: @Alex - With both the iron and the hot-air station. "Quicko T12-924" (aud $35 from Banggood) and "Yihua 959D", (aud $80 from ebay) each price includes delivery. :)

Comment: @enhzflep The second one won't run on 110V; but the first one, I wouldn't mind ordering.  Is it a good product though? -- I don't trust these "100% positive" reviews on Chinese sites, and I've received some products of inferior quality (e.g. a voltmeter that has a +/- 30 digits drift; so it drifts around while measuring a constant signal), and my negative review has been removed. But if you believe it's reliable, then I can invest a bit to try it out.  With soldering irons, the thing that typically is the problem is, that the tip typically wears out quite fast -- after 3-5 solders in one case.

Comment: For instance, reading their FAQ http://quickochina.com/FAQ/22.html (D) already gives a strong hint that the tips fail quite fast.  But if you've used it, my intuition might be wrong.

Comment: Also, found a comment on AliExpress saying that starting at 330 degrees, the temperature floats around, and that the sensor works incorrectly.  Again, might be a one-off case, but when I haven't had any experience with these, makes me suspicious.  https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32857656499.html?spm=2114.search0303.3.234.39ce11c3yFfD6K&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=732a87ed-97c3-43dc-977b-be8f0e64ae58&algo_expid=732a87ed-97c3-43dc-977b-be8f0e64ae58-37

Comment: @Alex - I bought them both using Coronavirus stimulus money. I certainly hate to waste anything, but figured they'd be a small enough gamble to be worth a shot. You should never use abrasive paper on a plated-tip, use a stainless-steel scourer (or much better, a copper one) I've had this thing at close to 400C for quite a while in the process of desoldering some stuff to get the hang of it. I bought 6 spare tips for about $25 and received them first. The K tip that came with the iron was slightly bent at the raised bump closest the hot end, but it's all I've used so far - works like a dream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113223/discussion-between-enhzflep-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

I took apart one of those coil things (mumble) years ago. It was something like 50 cents at the time (lol).

The entire construction was a thin aluminum tube with a fiberglass sleeve inside and some straight (not even coiled) Nichrome wire inside the fiberglass sleeve, terminated by (crimps, I think) to the wire from the cigarette lighter plug.

I would expect lead could be found in the solder to the plug and maybe tinning of the wires. Modern ones may have a fuse, switch and/or LED which might also have used lead. I would certainly not expect any lead to be in contact with the food.

Lead is not prohibited in electronics in many countries, and the use of lead typically is not only less expensive but superior in most ways, it's still available as an option, especially outside Europe.

Some of this stuff is pretty silly. I got a single brick shipped to me last week which not only has a California Prop 65 warning sticker on the box but recommends that the brick should be "stored locked up". Okay, it's got silica so if you cut it you should wear a respirator and clean up but they don't even have that "store locked up" warning on .45 caliber ammo, THC oil or tobacco.